# Sourcing a bash script from QT application

Tags: c++, bash, qt

I want to run a bash script that exports some environmental variables then use0 the exported variables in my qt application. I am able to get environmental variables using QprocessEnvironment. The problem is I can't source the script and running using Qprocess::execute() or Qprocess::startdetached() does not export the variables

Answer (score 0):

Source the env before starting the qt application.

```
#!/bin/bash
source my_env_settings
qt_application
```